# All possible combinations of k nonnegative integers summing to n

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $X_1$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution $\lambda = 1$ and assume it stands for a "number of earthquakes in next year". The same goes for $X_2 \dots X_n$(number of earthquakes 2 years from now, $\dots$, n years from now) and all of them are independent.

Now, let $Z_n$ be a random variable which denotes sum of earthquakes in next $n$ years. I am trying to find its distribution. The hint was to start with $Z_2$.

I see that:
$$
P(Z_2 = 0) = P(X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0) = P(X_1=0)P(X_2=0) \\
P(Z_2 = 1) = P(X_1=1)P(X_2=0) + P(X_1=0)P(X_2=1)\\
P(Z_2 = 2) = P(X_1=2)P(X_2=0) + P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1) + P(X_1=0)P(X_2=2) \\
\dots
$$

Is there an equation from which I could get "all possible combinations of k nonnegative integers summing to n"? I could then easily find $P(Z_n = k)$ and its distribution. It might have to do something with partitions, but it only gives me an answer "how many partitions are there" and I am looking for an equation which iterates over all of those partitions.

Comment: Use generating functions?

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Sums_of_Poisson-distributed_random_variables

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Presuming you've encountered them, moment-generating functions could be very useful here. Two facts you should recall about MGFs:

1. If $X, Y$ are independent with associated MGFs $m_x(t), m_y(t)$, then the MGF of $X+Y$ is $m_x(t) m_y(t)$.
2. Under certain reasonable conditions, MGFs are unique; that is, if you can calculate an MGF of a variable $Z$, and you recognize it to be the MGF of some known distribution, then $Z$ itself has that distribution.

Try answering the question for $n = 2$; I claim that it will illuminate the situation for general $n$.